# Why is tangent vector space, a vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry

From the notes I am using,

> For each point $p \in M$, the  tangent space to $M$ at point $p$ is the set

Where,

> Let $(M,O,A)$ be a smooth manifold. Let the curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M$, which is atleast $C^1$. Suppose $\gamma(\lambda_o)=p$. The velocity of $\gamma$ at the point $p$ of the curve is the linear map:
>
> $v_{\gamma,p}:C^{\infty} (M) \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> with, $v_{\gamma,p}(f)= (f \circ \gamma)'(p)$
>
> where,$C^{\infty}(M) := \{ f: M \to R|  \text{f is a smooth function }\}$
>
> equipped with $(f +  g)(p) = f(p) + g(p)$ and $(\lambda g)(p)= \lambda >\cdot g(p)$
>
> $$T_p M := \{v_{\gamma,p }| \text{ for all smooth curves } \gamma \text{ through p }\}$$
>
> With an addition and s multiplication defined the following way,
>
> $$+:T_p M \times T_p M \to Hom(C^{\infty} (M), \mathbb{R})$$
>
> $$(v_{\gamma,p} + v_{\delta,p} )(f) =v_{\gamma,p}(f)+ v_{\delta,p}(f)$$

> $$ \cdot: \mathbb{R} \times T_p M \to Hom(C^{\infty} (M),R)$$
> $$(\alpha \cdot v_{\gamma,p})(f):= \alpha \cdot v_{\gamma,p} (f)$$

In the standard vector space deifinition the **addition maps into another element in the vector space itself**. So, if $T_pM$ was a vector space then the addition must again map to $T_pM$ but here it doesn't, yet we call it a vector space, why?

Comment: What is your definition of $v_{\gamma, p}$? Given two such objects $v_{\gamma_1, p}$, $v_{\gamma_2, p}$, how was the addition defined? It seems like you only included the "type signature" for $+$.

Comment: Added how it acts @SamFreedman

Comment: that helps, but as mentioned below we still need to know what you mean by $v_{\gamma, p}$.

Comment: I've edited again, there was a symbol in the notes which looked like a direct sum and a tilted direct sum but I couldn't figure out how to write the tilted direct sum. So, I just wrote regular add and multiply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your definition of $T_p M$ is incomplete, it should be
$$ T_p M = \{ \text{all smooth curves $\gamma$ through $p$} \}/\sim $$
where two curves $\gamma$ and $\eta$ are equivalent under $\sim$
if their derivatives at $p$ (after you compose with a chart) are equal.

There is a natural injection
$$ i:T_p M \hookrightarrow \text{hom}(C^\infty(M), \mathbb{R})$$
where for a smooth curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $f \in C^\infty(M)$ we have
$$ i([\gamma]) (f) := (f \circ \gamma)'(0)$$.

Comment: Why is it not a bijection? Secondly why didn't the author just write this directly? Any reason the way in q may have been preferred?

Comment: If $p, q$ are not equal then the images of $T_p M$ and $T_q M$ under this injection are not contained in one another. Therefore it can not be surjective.

Comment: It seems to me the definition of the OP is correct, and it's different from the one you gave. Their definition is "all possible values $\gamma'(0)$ where $\gamma$ is a smooth curve passing through $p$". This does not require any identification. Maybe I am misreading something, though.

Comment: The image of $T_p M$ under $i$ is called the vector space of derivations at $p$. It is another way to look at the tangent space.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Well, without a choice of chart I don't think $\gamma'(0)$ makes sense when you have not defined a tangent space yet. And we want a definition that does not depend on a choice of chart.

Comment: @Tychonoff3000 Yes, I agree. What I think one should do here is ask the OP what their definition of $v_{\gamma,p}$ is, maybe even before answering. Given the quoted text, these are just vectors in some (potentially chart dependent) space defined in terms of $p$.